# Faile to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0

Tags: android, android-studio

Acabo de descargar Android Studio y me topo con una serie de errores al crear un nuevo proyecto.

¿Cómo los resuelvo?

Cabe recalcar que ya eh instalado el jdk y todos los requerimientos previos a la instalaciòn.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: tendras que instalar la última _support library_ probablemente

Answer (score 0):

El propio mensaje de error te indica que tienes que instalar el repositorio y sincronizar.

Pincha sobre: `Install Repository and sync project`